# How to make a bottom App Bar for the whole app on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout

I have implemented successfully a bottom app bar on my MainActivity. 
However, I wish it to be used on the whole app as well. 
Is there a clean code solution that uses that bar on other activities as well?

thanks in advance!

Comment: use fragment for each tab rather then using activity

Comment: but then they don't hide the main activity... Is there a possibility to a fragment totally hide its activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you to use Fragments in your app if you want a single BottomAppBar.

This article seems to be a good introdutction: https://proandroiddev.com/fragments-swapping-with-bottom-bar-ffbd265bd742

Comment: What if I have code on my main activity? Is it possible for a fragment to hide / totally cover its activity?

Comment: The activity has no longer content with this implementation, you will have a MainFragment for example, which holds the content of your current MainActivity.